# Selected dataTable row pushes to top

Tags: jquery, datatable

How to **Push** the selected row to top without sorting?

Or, when I've marked a row, that the **scroll menu** on the right center picked row . So, its in the **middle** of the **Data-Table**?

Comment: Since I haven't found any examples at all, and Im new to this I havent been able to test anything, been looking around and havent found anyone trying this with dataTable (what I have seen). I'm not after someone to write me code, just direct me to correct place since I cant be able to do this myself.

Comment: I have not seen such behaviour. Why you want to move to top?

Comment: Because sometimes I get results which is over 500, so I'd like it to either put the picked row to top, or make it center itself (so the row are showned instantly).

Comment: Why dont you just higlight the row?

Comment: I already do this. But still when you have a result of 500, there's alot of scrolling happening. And I wish it to instantly jump to the row or make it jump to the top (user friendly)

Comment: Do you want to do this only for datatables or you can use any other ?

Comment: It requires to use dataTable since it's just more than that behind it all, and I wouldn't want to remake everything. Thats why Im hoping there is some way (maybe even thru jquery?) to make it center the pressed row.

Comment: may be this link can give you idea http://jsfiddle.net/gguNM/2/

Comment: I'm going to try use .scrollTop() from jquery

Comment: Will you try and post the code if not working?

Comment: I'm going to use something like, $("div.demo").scrollTop(300); but instead of the 300 value. I will look in my class "row-selected" which height I selected then calculate value into that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it all by simply using

```
$('#' + id)[0].scrollIntoView();
```